# Limpiar toastr por medio de Jquery

Tags: jquery, validación

estoy usando toastr para los mensajes de alerta, pero el problema es que quiero que al cambiar de input todos los toastr desaparezcan, pero no se como hacerlo, en la pagina demo hay un boton que lo hace, pero no se como funciona.

En mi caso no seria con un boton sino que cuando cambie de focus desaparezcan todos los toastr.

Y otra pregunta que tengo hay alguna forma que por medio de jquery saber que mensaje tiene el toastr activo?
[Link de Toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/demo.html)

Esa es la pagina del demo, y el boton que yo digo que limpia todo es el que se llama `Clear Toasts` 
[image: Toastr]

Comment: Deberias de incluir tu codigo y lo que has intentado.

Comment: Cuando muestras lo que has intentado, motivas a que la comunidad te responda de mejor manera :D

Comment: @alanfcm intente pegar el boton que usan en el demo, ya que no se como funciona el limpiar, `<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="cleartoasts">Clear Toasts</button>`